# Document changes in a graph excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel doc that I keep track of finance things, and I'm updating it usually once a week or something. When I update I just replace previous data with new data.

I want to document the change in the cell's value in a graph so I can see the change in certain values over time.
Is it possible without the need to save previous data somewhere else manually?
What would be the best way to do this in terms of least amount of work maintaining it?
[image: This is the doc I'm using. I primarly want to track net worth change over time, and maybe certain assets.]
This is the doc I'm using. I primarly want to track net worth change over time, and maybe certain assets.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably need a record of the previous data somewhere in order to compare the latest data - it might be better to enter the new data underneath the previous and include a date so you know which is the latest version. Can you share a screenshot of the file with fake data? That'll help give you a better solution.

Comment: @lisboakotor Hey, thanks for the answer! I added a screenshot of the excel table I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the historical data somewhere in the file in order to be able to track changes.

I'd suggest having one worksheet for Assets, one for Debt, one for Net Worth, one for Pensions etc. and maybe an 'Overview' sheet if you want the latest values in one place (you can use lookup functions like VLOOKUP or INDEX and MATCH to get the latest values from the Assets, Debt (etc.) worksheets). If you try and record weekly data for everything on one sheet, it might get messy/confusing quite quickly.

One possible format on the Assets worksheet would be something like the below. Each asset has its own column and when you add new data, you only have to enter it into its column. You could do something similar for Debt and then use a formula on the Net Worth sheet to calculate the value for each of the dates, and create any charts you want to update automatically.

[image: Excel screenshot of potential solution where each date is a row and each asset is a column, to help OP track changes over time]

A slightly more complex format might be to use what you have but insert a Date column and add additional rows when you add new data. This might be a bit more work to update and there might be some difficulty creating charts for specific assets with this, but you get to keep more of the info in one place.

[image: Excel screenshot of potential solution where the OP's format is used but a date column is added, to help track changes over time]